# got an exception in c# develop windows phone

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-8

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Type 'xxx.Cost+RootObject' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.
  Source=System.Runtime.Serialization
  InnerException:
```

i saw another posts and some people suggest to add data contract and data member. could you please help me where can i put data member and data contract? i still don't get it.

here is my class code:

```
namespace xxx
{
    class Cost
    {
        public class Title
        {
            public string from { get; set; }
            public string to { get; set; }
            public string from_zip { get; set; }
            public string to_zip { get; set; }
            public string from_suburb { get; set; }
            public string to_suburb { get; set; }
        }

        public class Content
        {
            public string company { get; set; }
            public string package { get; set; }
            public string rate { get; set; }
            public string rate_second { get; set; }
            public string est_time { get; set; }
            public string inclusion { get; set; }
            public string exclusion { get; set; }
            public string last_update { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Title title { get; set; }
            public List<Content> content { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the documentation on the serialization contracts at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx

In your case, you need to annotate your classes with the `DataContract` attribute, and members that you wish to be serialized with `DataMember`, as shown below.

```cs
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
class Cost
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Title
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string from { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string to { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string from_zip { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string to_zip { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string from_suburb { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string to_suburb { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Content
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string company { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string package { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string rate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string rate_second { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string est_time { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string inclusion { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string exclusion { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string last_update { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Title title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Content> content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way, is there any shorter way to do with the class without using datamember and datacontract?

Comment: You need to add reference to "System.Runtime.Serialization" manually, project ->Add reference.